# Find first occuring events in SQL

Tags: sql, date, select, mariadb, greatest-n-per-group

### The problem

In our application we store recurring events for when a room should be cleaned. The task (event) is assigned to a user and is given a category. We use a SQL-view, `cleaning_tasks`, to get all scheduled tasks for a particular day. The view would return something like the following.

```sql
SELECT * FROM cleaning_tasks WHERE scheduled_at = current_date();

> room_id, user_id, category, scheduled_at
>       1,       1,        3,   2020-06-04
```

The issue now is that we want to get the first upcoming event grouped by `room_id`, `user_id` and `category`.

For example, say we have three rooms with category 1 which must be cleaned daily and two rooms with category 2 which are cleaned every Friday. If today is Wednesday then I want the query to return three events for category 1 and the two events with category 2 which are scheduled to occur on Friday (the rows marked with a `*`.) If it was Friday then the query would return all five events scheduled at Friday.

```
room_id, user_id, category, scheduled_at
----------------------------------------
     10,       1,        1,   2020-06-03 * # Wednesday 
     20,       2,        1,   2020-06-03 *
     30,       3,        1,   2020-06-03 *
     10,       1,        1,   2020-06-04   # Thursday
     20,       2,        1,   2020-06-04
     30,       3,        1,   2020-06-04
     10,       1,        1,   2020-06-05   # Friday
     20,       2,        1,   2020-06-05
     30,       3,        1,   2020-06-05
     40,       4,        2,   2020-06-05 *         
     50,       5,        2,   2020-06-05 *
```

### My attempts

I've tried the following query and I get the right results, but I'm not sure the results will always be correct due to the `GROUP BY`. The events the SQL-view is retrieving are created sequentially.

```sql
SELECT room_id, user_id, category, scheduled_at
FROM room_cleaning_tasks
WHERE scheduled_at >= current_date()
GROUP BY room_id, user_id, category
```

I first tried using `MIN` but noticed I got the wrong results. Probably due to `GROUP BY`.

```sql
SELECT room_id, user_id, category, scheduled_at, MIN(scheduled_at)
FROM cleaning_tasks
WHERE scheduled_at >= current_date()
GROUP_BY room_id, user_id, category
```

I also tried to use `MIN` in a subquery but that did not work. I'm pretty sure the the inner join fails because of `MIN` in the subquery.

```sql
SELECT t.room_id, t.user_id, t.category, t.scheduled_at
FROM (
  SELECT room_id, user_id, category, MIN(scheduled_at) scheduled_at
  FROM cleaning_tasks
  GROUP BY room_id, user_id, category
) upcoming
INNER JOIN cleaning_tasks
  ON t.room_id = upcoming.room_id
  AND t.user_id = upcoming.user_id
  AND t.category = upcoming.category
  AND t.category >= current_date()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One usually efficient option is to filter with a subquery:

```
select ct.* 
from cleaning_tasks ct
where ct.scheduled_at = (
    select min(ct1.scheduled_at)
    from cleaning_tasks ct1
    where ct1.room_id = ct.room_id and ct1.scheduled_at >= current_date
)
```

For performance, consider an index on `(room_id, scheduled_at)`.

Comment: Sadly this query did not work for me. I also added `ct1.user_id = ct.user_id and ct1.category = ct.category`. It only found events scheduled for current_date.

Comment: @Gradox: [here is a db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=361cc0b541df09e3d32c4c9ebaef53d1). It seems to work fine and produce the expected results (I filtered on `room_id` `10`, as described in your question).

Comment: Maybe I worded the question poorly, but those results are not the ones I am after. In the example room 10 should only appear once per `user_id` per `category` per `scheduled_at`. In your fiddle room 10 appears three times. In that case I should only appear once with the scheduled_at = 2020-06-03 because it is the event which is closes or equal to `current_date`.

Again, I am sorry if I was unclear.

Comment: @Gradox: ah ok, so that’s even simpler! I modified my answer (and added a recommendation for performance).

Comment: I had still had to compare `user_id` and `category_id` to get the desired results, but I am 99% sure the query returns exactly what I want.
You solution looks simpler than @notmak 's so I'll mark yours as the accepted answer. Still, thanks to both of you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly you want the first "scheduled_at" date on or after today grouped by room, user, and category.

I would use a ROWNUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY) and put it in a subquery so you can filter.

For example:

```
SELECT SUB.*
FROM (
      SELECT ROOM_ID
      , USER_ID
      , CATEGORY
      , SCHEDULED_AT
      , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ROOM_ID, USER_ID, CATEGORY 
                           ORDER BY SCHEDULED_AT ASC) AS ITEM_NUMBER
      FROM CLEANING_TASKS
      WHERE SCHEDULED_AT >= CURRENT_DATE
      ) SUB
WHERE ITEM_NUMBER = 1
```

Comment: I think this query gives me the correct rows. I will have to do some testing tomorrow, but it looks promising!

Comment: Although both queries work, this solution turned out to be much faster given our dataset in production.